# Getting main document's name when using subfiles

Tags: subfiles, multiple-files

When using the `subfiles` package, is there some command to get the main document's name, even when compiling one of the child documents?

Here's a MWE showing what I mean:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
%
\begin{filecontents*}{main.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\end{filecontents*}
%
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
Child document's name: \jobname % this displays 'Child document's name: <the_name_you_gave_to_this_document>

Main document's name: % <some_command>  -- this should display 'Main document's name: main'
\end{document}
```

Where `<some_command>` is the command I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option you pass to the `subfiles` class is stored in `\preamble@file`, which is later `\input` by the class. To get the base name of the file you can use LaTeX's `\filename@parse`, which will store the base name in `\filename@base`:

```latex
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
%
\begin{filecontents*}{main.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\makeatletter
\let\noibe@ifloaded\@ifl@aded
\def\mainfilename{%
  \noibe@ifloaded{cls}{subfiles}%
    {\filename@parse{\preamble@file}\filename@base}
    {\jobname}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Child document's name: \jobname % this displays 'Child document's name: <the_name_you_gave_to_this_document>

Main document's name: \mainfilename % -- this should display 'Main document's name: main'
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}
%
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}
\makeatletter
\let\noibe@ifloaded\@ifl@aded
\def\mainfilename{%
  \noibe@ifloaded{cls}{subfiles}%
    {\filename@parse{\preamble@file}\filename@base}
    {\jobname}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Child document's name: \jobname % this displays 'Child document's name: <the_name_you_gave_to_this_document>

Main document's name: \mainfilename % -- this should display 'Main document's name: main'
\end{document}
```

The command checks if the loaded class is `subfiles`. If it is, you're in a child file and the main file name is stored in `\preamble@file`. Otherwise you're in the main file and the file name is `\jobname` itself. When you're in the main file the command `\preamble@file` does not exist, so the command checks which class is loaded and acts accordingly.

Comment: One minor hiccup: this returns `main.tex`, how can I remove the `.tex` and simply get `main`?

Comment: @noibe I updated the answer.

Comment: Another (this time not so) minor hiccup: that code only works when compiling the "child" file. If I try to use it in the main file, I get the error `Undefined control sequence. <argument> \preamble@file`.

Comment: @noibe Updated again :-)

Comment: Hey thanks a lot man :)